# How do I make it so when people save my mobile website to their homescreen it removes Safari like Kahoot.it?

Tags: jquery, ios, css, safari

So if you save Kahoot.it to the iPad, it removes most of Safari to make it look like a standalone app. However, if I do the same, it just opens up in Safari. How do I make it do exactly what Kahoot.it does? I have provided screenshots:

[original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DvmpM.jpg)

[kahoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6gB23.png)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/ConfiguringWebApplications/ConfiguringWebApplications.html

Google Chrome also has a similar function more information can be found below.
https://developers.google.com/web/progressive-web-apps/